# On Change event doesn't work Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-events

I think that is simple but I don't know what happens. I am trying to use (on) event in Jquery to disable a button, when the users choose an option in a select box the button should change its state. However, it doesn't work. This is my Jquery code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#bOK').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#GRP15').on('change', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (this.value > 0){
        $('#bOK').attr('disabled', false);
      } else {
        $('#bOK').attr('disabled', true);   
      }
    });
});
```

this is my select box:

```
<select id="GRP15" name="GRP15" onchange="updateActivityTotals(true, 'G', '15', document.getElementsByName('PriceExcVAT'+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)[0], document.getElementsByName('Price'+this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)[0]);">
  <option value="0">--- Please Select ---</option>
  <option value="150">28th September 2015</option>
  <option value="153">29th September 2015</option>
  <option value="155">30th September 2015</option> 
</select>
```

Of course, I notice that there is a onchange event inline but I can't remove that because this event is come from the system. I think that is the problem but my code work sometimes for example if I use :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#bOK').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#GRP15').on('change', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert(this.value);
    });
});
```

This code show me the value although sometimes it doesn't work.
This is my button:

```
<input type="BUTTON" class="button bOK" name="bOK" id="bOK" value="Next >" onclick="document.EVENTFORM.submit();">
```

Any suggestion? please.
Kind Regards.

Comment: Try `$('#GRP15').click(function(){})` or  `$('#GRP15').live('click',function(){})`

Comment: Can you just add your code to disable/enable the button to the `updateActivityTotals` function?

Comment: I believe the error comes from elsewhere because it's working in this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/u66o65rr/1/ Maybe the function updateActivityTotals stops the event from executing any further code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling onchange event twice in code. one is in select code itself and other in document.ready. That's why first jquery code executed properly and second one not.

You should use it once. So try change `updateActivityTotals` function like below:

```
function updateActivityTotals(a,b,c,d,e) {
  //your previous code
  .......
  .....

  // All other code also goes here 
  if (this.value > 0){
    $('#bOK').attr('disabled', false);
  } else {
    $('#bOK').attr('disabled', true);   
  } 
}
```

Comment: I updated the function and everything work fine. Thanks.